# Display label for Menu, Task Pane in Outlook Web Addin

Tags: fabricjs, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

In Outlook web addin I have provided the following property

```
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="My test addin" />
```

This property is used in the following three locations:

1. In main Menu which shows up on clicking the three dots "..." on the right of an email :

[image]

2. On the custom addin page :

[image]

3. On the addin header :

[image]

All of the above three locations use the same label property and image. Is there a way to provide a different text label for each of the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the feature to customize the display name at different locations, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.